# Compile Applescript to run on Mountain Lion "unidentified developer"

Tags: cocoa, applescript, osx-mountain-lion

I'm using osacompile to compile an AppleScript into an app bundle in Mountain Lion but I cannot execute the resulting bundle as it complains that the developer is unidentified as I would expect from an unsigned app bundle. I've noticed that Photoshop and other apps can create droplet bundles that run fine and on inspection of their contents they do not appear to be signed. How can I compile a script to be allowed to execute?

UPDATE: This appears to only be a problem when osacompile is run from an `NSTask` within my app, if I compile the same script via command line the resulting bundle runs fine.

UPDATE 2: This seems to be related to the com.apple.quarantine xattr being applied to the bundle. I can't figure out a way to compile the applescript without the resulting bundle having the quarantine attribute applied.

Answer (score 0):

[Sign My Scripts](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/apps/readmyscripts.html) is a free app that allows you to codesign AppleScript-based apps using your Apple Developer ID. If you are a developer, use this to sign your app bundle.